# How to tell word to not line break across a region of text?

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-word-2011, linebreaks

I have a Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 document that includes some numbers with exponents and I don't want line breaks in the middle of the figures.  For example:

> 100 lb×in<sup>-2</sup>

Sometimes gets rendered in a paragraph like this:

> A bunch of text goes here pushing value to end of line, 100 lb×in<sup>-</sup>
>
> <sup>2</sup> continuing here with the line break between negative sign and two.

I really just want the whole 'lb×in<sup>-2</sup>' value to all be on one line and never broken in the middle.  This is kind of like the concept of `&nbsp;` on web pages, but I want each character of the units to be no-breaking.  I can always force a line-feed with `shift-return` but that is brittle as the preceding text may change over time causing the forced line-feed to be out of position.

Is there a way in Word for Mac 2011 to instruct Microsoft to not cause a line-break in a section of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use a non-breaking hyphen.  Type `Command-Shift-hypen` on a Mac to insert one in Word.  It shows as long when paragraph and other non-printing character display is enabled, but it is same length as normal hyphen when printed or that feature is turned off.

> A bunch of text goes here pushing value to end of line, 100
>
> lb×in<sup>-2</sup> continuing here with the line break between negative sign and two.

Add a non-breaking space `Ctrl-Shift-space` to force the number to stick with the units too.

> A bunch of text goes here pushing value to end of line,
>
> 100 lb×in<sup>-2</sup> continuing here with the line break between negative sign and two.

Answer (score 0):

General solution is to wrap your text with the EQ field.  Please see [my Q & A here](https://superuser.com/a/1717884/1631501)

Hope it helps. Good luck!