# Word: how to prevent line break in fields? No VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, linebreaks

I am preparing a Word document with fields that may be located anywhere and may contain spaces and dashes.  So, a field may be line broken when located at the end of a line.  I need to get rid of this.  VBA is unavailable.

[image]

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unclear what you mean. 'Disable hyphenation'?

Comment: @Aganju. No.  I need a field to be on a single line.  Unless it is not longer than this line.

Comment: Where are the contents of the field coming from? You could put non-breaking spaces and hyphens at the source. Without vba, there is no way to change what is displayed the way you want.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon, thanks for the reply! The fields that I need to keep on a single line come from Doc Properties, and they definitely contain hyphens and spaces. Yes, it is  easy to replace hyphens and spaces with non-breaking ones using VBA, but VBA is not an option here.

Comment: If the Doc Properties are the "Cover Page" properties which are under Quick Parts, you can enter non-breaking spaces and hyphens, and for that matter, do not need the fields. You can enter them directly in the Document/Template. https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart

Comment: @CharlesKenyon, No, they are custom Doc Properties containing document numbers and equipment part numbers. Thanks anyway for the helpful information!

Comment: You can, never the less repurpose the cover page document properties. See the page previously linked.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon.  Hopefully you know that Quick Parts | Doc Property is not a field. Using fields is the requirement. That is why I wrote the word "field" in the main topic above. Nevertheless, thanks again!

Comment: I know it is not a field. I thought it would serve your purpose as well as, or perhaps better than, a DocProperty field. There is no way, short of vba to do what you want with fields. Is using fields the requirement of some superintendent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the field with EQ field :

[image]